# Save a numpy sparse matrix into file

Tags: numpy, save, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I want to save the result of TfidfVectorizer in sklearn.feature_extraction.text into a text file for future use. As I found, it is a sparse matrix of type ''. However when I try to save it using the following code

```
np.savetxt('Feature_TfIdf.txt', X_Tfidf, fmt='%2.6f')
```

I get an error like this

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `joblib.dump` or `sklearn.externals.joblib.dump` for this. NumPy doesn't get SciPy sparse matrices.

Comment: While `np.savetxt` can't save the sparse matrix because it doesn't have a method to convert it to text, `np.save` does work - it wraps the sparse matrix in an object dtype array, and saves that as a binary.

Comment: Could you provide an example? @Fred

Answer (score 1):

Simple example:

```
np.save('TfIdf.pkl',tfidf)
```

Comment: And load with `np.load('TfIdf.pkl.npy', allow_pickle=True)`

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve the problem by converting the sparse matrix to full matrix and then save matrix and save the results. This approach however is not useful for large arrays so it is better to save the matrix in .pkl format.